# XSLT value not populating in a condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Below is the XML i am using.

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <empName>ABC</empName>
        <desgination>SSE</desgination>
        <age></age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <empName>DEF</empName>
        <desgination>VP</desgination>
        <age></age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <empName>GHI</empName>
        <desgination>Lead</desgination>
        <age></age>
    </employee>        
</employees>
```

and below is the XSL i am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:my="some.uri" version="1.0">

    <my:EMPNames>
        <entry key="ABC">true</entry>
        <entry key="XYZ">true</entry>
        <entry key="JHK">true</entry>        
    </my:EMPNames>

    <xsl:template match="//employee[document('')/*/my:EMPNames/entry[@key = empName]]">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am unable to print employee section whose empName is ABC. 
I am using Key-Value pair list. If the incoming xml empName has the value in list i want to print that employee section. Somehow i am not able to get the value for `//employee[document('')/*/my:EMPNames/entry[@key = empName]]` can you please let me know what i am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the expression `//employee[document('')/*/my:EMPNames/entry[@key = empName]]` is the final xpath predicate `entry[@key = empName]`. This means you are looking for an **entry** who has a **@key** attribute equal to its child element **empName**. In other words, it is looking for the **empName** under the **entry** element.

What you need to do is this.

```
<xsl:template match="//employee[empName = document('')/*/my:EMPNames/entry/@key]">
```

Or if you only want to include ones where the **entry** is true, do this

```
<xsl:template 
    match="//employee[empName = document('')/*/my:EMPNames/entry[. = 'true']/@key]">
```